# boost shared memory between 32bit and 64bit in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, shared-memory

I'm trying to use the boost 1.58 interprocess library to share memory between processes and need it to support both 32bit and 64bit processes.

I've been following advice from the boost mailinglist to get this working but I get compile errors for 32-bit builds (and only there) on Visual c++ (both 2013 and 2015).

This is a minimal sample that exposes the compile errors:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/offset_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstdint>


namespace bi = boost::interprocess;
typedef bi::offset_ptr<void, std::int32_t, std::uint64_t> VoidPointerT;
typedef bi::basic_managed_shared_memory<char, bi::rbtree_best_fit<bi::mutex_family, VoidPointerT>, bi::iset_index> my_managed_shared_memory;


int main()
{
  my_managed_shared_memory shm(bi::open_or_create, "test", 1024);

  return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error C2719: 'x': formal parameter with __declspec(align('8')) won't be aligned
```

in many different headers of boost.

I understand that I can fix this error by replacing call-by-value parameter passing in the reported functions by call-by-reference but in my actual application the problem occurs in dozens of places all over the library. Is there a better way?

Comment: this compliles *just fine* on both 32 and 64bit. I am using boost 1.60.0 and MSVC 2013 Express.
As a note: your example helped me to solve my problem. Your definition of ´my_managed_shared_memory´ gave me the correct hint. Thanks.

Comment: interesting, maybe boost 1.60 changed something. For completeness: I currently use this declaration which seems to work in boost 1.58. Not sure why and how but yeah, it compiles and everything appears stable:
typedef bi::offset_ptr<void, std::int32_t, std::uint64_t> VoidPointerT;
typedef bi::basic_managed_shared_memory<char, bi::rbtree_best_fit<bi::mutex_family, VoidPointerT, 8>, bi::iset_index> my_managed_shared_memory;